# What can be said about these ratios of third and first derivatives?

Tags: inequality

Let's say that we have function $u:\mathbb R_0\to \mathbb R$ with $u'(x)>0$, $u''(x)<0$, $u'''(x)>0$, $\lim_{x\to 0} u'(x) = \infty, \lim_{x\to 0}u'(x) = 0$.

Take $x_1 < x_2$. Does $$\frac{u'''(x_1)}{u'''(x_2)}\leq  \frac{u'(x_1)}{u'(x_2)}$$ always hold?

Thanks, I'm lost here.

Comment: What do you mean by R_0?

Comment: ... and how can $\lim_{x \to 0} u'(x)$ be both "inf" (I assume $\infty$ and $0$?

Comment: I would guess that this is from the positive reals to the reals and the second limit is as $x \to \infty$

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 1):

No, the ratio $u'''/u'$ need not be monotone. Since there is no restriction on the fourth derivative, nothing prevents us from adding a spike to $u'''$ that will destroy its monotonicity without violating any other constraints.

More concretely, let $u$ be a function as in the statement. Let  $$v(x)=u(x)+  \delta \epsilon^3 \sin (2\pi \epsilon^{-1}x)\chi_{[1\le x\le 1+\epsilon]} \tag1$$ 
Ignoring insufficient smoothness* at $1$ and $1+\epsilon$, we see that $v$, $v'$ and $v''$ are within $\delta\epsilon $ of the corresponding $u$ derivatives. Also, $v'''-u''' $ is of order $\delta$. Fix $\delta$ small enough so that $v'''$ is positive. Now make $\epsilon$ very small. The added term in (1) has huge 4th derivative (first positive, then negative), and this makes  $v'''$ non-monotone.

(*) Instead of one period of sine function, one should use a smoother compactly supported function, such as convolution of one period of sine with a smooth bump function.